# How to swap spinner value while clicking image

Tags: java, android

Im very new for android, I want swap spinner value when user click the image. Please anyone help me.

Here my code:

```js
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {
    ImageView swap;
    Spinner source, destination;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.search, container,
                false);
        swap = (ImageView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.imgSwap);
        source = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.from);
        destination = (Spinner)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.to);


        swap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                
            -----> \\Here want to code    
          
            
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Comment: From swap spinner value what I understand is you want to change values of spinner drop-down if so you can easily done it by changing spinner adapter

Comment: What do you what to swap??

Comment: I want to swap selected spinner value

Answer (score 0):

If you want to swap the contents of two Spinners you can use this

```
        ArrayList<String> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        list1.add("A");
        list1.add("B");
        list1.add("C");

        list2.add("1");
        list2.add("2");
        list2.add("3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list1);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,list2);

        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

       yourImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayAdapter<String> a1 = (ArrayAdapter) spinner1.getAdapter();
            ArrayAdapter<String> a2 = (ArrayAdapter) spinner2.getAdapter();

            spinner1.setAdapter(a2);
            spinner2.setAdapter(a1);
        }
    });
```

Or if you just want to swap the selected values across the spinner you can use this in your button click

```
      yourImagebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position1 = spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();
            int position2 = spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition();

            String item1 = list1.get(position1);
            String item2 = list2.get(position2);

            list1.remove(position1);
            list1.add(position1, item2);

            list2.remove(position2);
            list2.add(position2, item1);

            adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```